# Find the largest possible delta-neighborhood to a given epsilon.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

**Problem:**

$ \lim_{x \to \pi} [[x]] = 3   $, where $\epsilon = 0.01$

([[x]] denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to x)

**My thoughts:**

> Given a $\epsilon = 0.01$, $ \exists \delta > 0   $ such that $ 0< |x - \pi| < \delta  \Rightarrow  |[[x]] - 3| < \epsilon$.
>   The Definition of $[[x]]$ gives $x - 4 < [[x]] - 3 < x -3 $.

And I am stuck from here as I don't know how to connect $ [[x]] - 3$ and $|x - \pi| $.

I appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, when $x$ is close to $\pi, [[x]]$ is guaranteed to be $3$. You just need to make sure $3 \le x \lt 4$ to have $[[x]]=3$

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't know how to find the $\delta$ after knowing the bound of x

Comment: You wrote $0< |x - \pi| < \delta  \Rightarrow  |[[x]] - 3| < \epsilon$  What is the least distance between $x$ and $\pi$ that can cause $[[x]]$ not to be $3$?

Comment: $|[[x]] - 3| < 0.01$ forces $3 \le x < 4$. Thus $|x - \pi$| < $4 - \pi$, hence, I can choose $\delta = 4 - \pi$ ?

Comment: No, because you need $x - \delta \gt 3$.  The largest $\delta$ can be is $\pi-3$.  You need a symmetric $\delta$ neighborhood around $\pi$ where $[[x]]=3$